# AWS CodeDeploy under AWS Educate Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy, bitbucket-aws-code-deploy

I am having some trouble doing code deploy with my AWS Educate account. Initially, when I was setting things up I was following this article.

https://hackernoon.com/deploy-to-ec2-with-aws-codedeploy-from-bitbucket-pipelines-4f403e96d50c?fbclid=IwAR3rezVMGpuQxTJ3AneOeTL2oMHjCKbQB5C5ouTLhJQ5gRp3JeL4GK0f53o

In it is talks about setting up an IAM service account. The problem is that AWS Educate allows you to create the accounts but it won't generate keys. In order for me to deploy my Spring Boot (and VueJS) apps to my s3 buckets and ec2s from my bitbucket repo, I need a key and secret key and CodeDeploy Group.

Fine I was able to use my Click the Account Details button on the labs.vocareum page and get my keys, however when I am attempting to set up a Code Deploy Group it asks for a service role and I am unsure where to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why is the service role necessary?

The service role is used by the CodeDeploy service in order to perform actions outside CodeDeploy (i.e. on another service such as S3).

AWS has a special approach of integrating services. Basically, you have to give each service you are using explicit permission to use another service (even if the access stays in the bounds of the same account). There is no inherent permission given to the CodeDeploy service to change things in S3. In fact, CodeDeploy is not even allowed to read files from S3 without explicitly allowing it.

Here is the official explanation from the docs [1]:

> In AWS, service roles are used to grant permissions to an AWS service so it can access AWS resources. The policies that you attach to the service role determine which AWS resources the service can access and what it can do with those resources.

### What you are actually doing according to the hackernoon article

1. you need a user account with programmatic access to your aws account
2. the user account needs to have a policy attached which grants permission to upload files into S3 and trigger a CodeDeploy deployment --> you provide the access key and secret access key of this user to Bitbucket so it can upload the stuff into S3 and trigger a deployment on bahalf of your user identity
3. Unrelated to steps 1 and 2: Create a role in AWS IAM [2] which will be used by both services (NOT Bitbucket): CodeDeploy and EC2. Strictly speaking, the author of the hackernoon article is merging two steps into one here: You are creating one role which is used by **both** services (as specified by the two different principals in the trust relationship: *ec2.amazonaws.com* and *codedeploy.us-west-2.amazonaws.com*). Usually this is **not** how IAM policies should be configured because it violates the principle of granting least privilege [4] as the EC2 instances receives permissions from the *AWSCodeDeployRole* policy which it probably does not need as far as I see. But that is just a philosophical note here. All the steps mentioned in the hackernoon article should technically work.

So, what you actually do is:

- granting CodeDeploy permission to perform various actions inside your account, such as viewing which EC2 instances you have started etc. (this is specified inside the policy AWSCodeDeployRole [3])
- granting EC2 permission to read the revision which was uploaded to S3 (this is specified inside the policy AmazonS3FullAccess)

#### To get back to your question...

> However when I am attempting to set up a Code Deploy Group it asks for a service role and I am unsure where to get this?

You need to create the service role by yourself inside the IAM service (see [2]). I do not know if this is supported by AWS Educate, but I guess it should be. After creating the service role, you MUST assign it to the CodeDeploy Group (that is the point where you are stuck right now). Moreover, you must assign that same service role to you EC2 instance profile.

### References

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/getting-started-create-service-role.html
[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_for-service.html#roles-creatingrole-service-console
[3] https://github.com/SummitRoute/aws_managed_policies/blob/master/policies/AWSCodeDeployRole
[4] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html#grant-least-privilege

Comment: I'm slightly embarrassed, I missed creating the role.